# Motivation for Definition of Tensor Product of Modules

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, motivation

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $M,N,P$ be A-modules.I know that tensor product of $M$ and $N$ is a universal object ($ M \otimes N$,u) (where $M \otimes N$ is a $A$-module and $u: M\times N \to M\otimes N$ is a bilinear map) with the following universal property:

**Universal Property:** Given any bilinear map $ \phi: M\times N \to P$ there exist a unique **Linear** map $f: M\otimes N \to P$ such that $\phi=f o u$.

I've read the construction of tensor product but I don't really see the motivation for the definition of tensor product.I mean why do we need such an object? Why do we define tensor product with the above universal property.What was the Motivation for such definition of tensor product?

Comment: Bilinear maps come up naturally (any time you have a notion of multiplication, really) but most of linear algebra is set up to deal with linear things. Tensor products convert bilinear to linear.

Comment: If you know category theory: The tensor product gives a left adjoint to the Hom-functor (fixing one argument). If you care about Hom, you should care about the tensor product. (It could be argued that this is just a more abstract way to phrase what @Hoot mentioned.)